# Extract text name from String

Tags: r

I have a column with value as

"RED LOBSTER CA04606" or 
"Red Lobster NewYork WY245" n so on

How can I extract just the name Red Lobster or Red Lobster NewYork from it. Am tryin to using the stringr package. 
Is there a way to check if its text only and can ignore the values with numbers in them?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thanks all folks, so many options now I can do this :) .. .. Much appreciated for your prompt replies.

Comment: do you want to match complete words without numbers?

Comment: Complete match is not required, I just had to separate out rest names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to use `stringr`, I recommend `str_extract` (I'd recommend it even if you weren't trying to use `stringr`):

```
x <- c('RED LOBTSER CA04606', 'Red Lobster NewYork WY245')
str_extract(x, '[a-zA-Z ]+\\b')
# [1] "RED LOBSTER "          "Red Lobster NewYork "
```

The '\b' in the regex prevents the 'CA' from 'CA04606' being extracted.

If you don't like that trailing space you could use `str_trim` to remove it, or you could modify the regex:

```
str_extract(x, '[a-zA-Z]+(?: +[a-zA-Z]+)*\\b')
# [1] "RED LOBSTER"          "Red Lobster NewYork"
```

Note - if your string has non-numbers *after* the post code, the above only returns the words before. So in the example below, if you wanted to get the 'NewYork' after the 'WY245', you can use `str_extract_all` and paste the results together:

```
x <- c(x, 'Red Lobster WY245 NewYork')
str_extract_all(x, '[a-zA-Z]+(?: +[a-zA-Z]+)*\\b')
# [[1]]
# [1] "RED LOBSTER"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Red Lobster NewYork"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "Red Lobster" "NewYork"    

# Paste the bits together with paste(..., collapse=' ')
sapply(str_extract_all(x, '[a-zA-Z]+(?: +[a-zA-Z]+)*\\b'), paste, collapse=' ')
# [1] "RED LOBSTER"          "Red Lobster NewYork" "Red Lobster NewYork"
```

Comment: thanks @mathematical-coffee .. this perfect for me to write a full function.

Answer (score 3):

Try `gsub`

```
> x <- "RED LOBSTER CA04606"
> gsub("\\S*\\d+\\S*",'', x)
[1] "RED LOBSTER "

> x<-"Red Lobster NewYork WY245"
> gsub("\\S*\\d+\\S*",'', x)
[1] "Red Lobster NewYork "

> x<-"Red Lobster NewYork WY245 BLUE LOBSTER CA04606"
> gsub("\\S*\\d+\\S*",'', x)
[1] "Red Lobster NewYork  BLUE LOBSTER "
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of `strsplit` and `grepl`

```
 sapply(strsplit(x, ' '), function(x) paste(x[!grepl('[[:digit:]]',x)], collapse = ' '))
```

This splits by space, then tests whether there are digits splitted vector, and only pastes together those without numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative `gsub` version:

```
x <- c("RED LOBSTER CA04606","Red Lobster NewYork WY245")

gsub("(.+)\\s+(.+$)","\\1",x)
[1] "RED LOBSTER"         "Red Lobster NewYork"
```

and to get the other part of the text:

```
gsub("(.+)\\s+(.+$)","\\2",x)
[1] "CA04606" "WY245"
```

Answer (score 0):

this is step by step

```
mystr<-"Red Lobster NewYork WY245"
r<-regexpr("[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]+", mystr)
s<-substr(mystr, r[1], r[1] + attr(r, "match.length"))
mystr<-sub(s, "", mystr)
```