# Check for same value we have same unique value in other column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have below-mentioned dataframe:

Note: I have ~0.2 million of rows in dataframe, and want to run logic throughout the dataframe.

```
ID Num MAX CH
1  22  A   XCA-1
2  24  B   VBS-1
3  54  A   XCA-1
4  48  A   XCA-1
5  88  C   CXV-1
6  87  B   VBS-1
7  98  A   VBS-0
```

How to check for every `MAX` value we have same `CH` throughout the dataframe and add a new column with status (i.e Match or Not Match).

Required Dataframe:

```
ID Num MAX CH  ST
1  22  A   XCA-1 Not Match
2  24  B   VBS-7 Match
3  54  A   XCA-1 Not Match
4  48  A   XCA-1 Not Match
5  88  C   CXV-4 Match
6  87  B   VBS-7 Match
7  98  A   VBS-0 Not Match
```

Comment: You have to extract the first part from `$CH` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779145/extract-text-name-from-string or simply `substr()` or `substring()` ) and compare it with `$MAX`.

Comment: @jogo that was just for example, in original dataframe i don't have anything to extract and match.

Comment: What does that mean? Do you have a `CH` column in your data? You'll have to show what your data looks like if you want exact answers. Else @jogo's comment gives fair enough direction

Comment: @ClockSlave Thanks, I have restructured the question accordingly.

Comment: So how do we match this? In the fourth row, you have `XCA-1`. this has `C` and `A` as well. How do we know its a match or not?

Comment: Does having the the letter `A` mean its match regardless of position, etc?

Comment: @ClockSlave I want to check `MAX` and `CH` , in ideal scenarios the For same `MAX` Value we should have same `CH` Value, but wherever it's different give me `ST` as `Not Match`. Let me restructure it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  After grouping by 'MAX', get the unique number of 'CH' as a logical vector to populate the 'Not Match', 'Match' and assign it to 'ST2' to create the column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, ST2 := c("Not Match", "Match")[(uniqueN(CH) == 1) + 1], MAX]
df1
#   ID Num MAX    CH       ST2
#1:  1  22   A XCA-1 Not Match
#2:  2  24   B VBS-1     Match
#3:  3  54   A XCA-1 Not Match
#4:  4  48   A XCA-1 Not Match
#5:  5  88   C CXV-1     Match
#6:  6  87   B VBS-1     Match
#7:  7  98   A VBS-0 Not Match
```

Comment: variant: `...[, ST2 := ifelse(uniqueN(CH) == 1, "Match", "Not Match"), MAX]`

Comment: @jogo Thanks, Initially I was thinking about `if/else`, but it could be a bit slow

Comment: @akrun For some cases i don't have MAX value in dataframe for that i want to check ID and Num in entire dataframe and whenever either ID or Num match anywhere in the dataframe that compare CH value of particular row and give Match if value same or Not Match in Status.

Comment: @VectorJX  That looks like a separate condition.  Could you post that as a new question

Comment: @akrun As suggested:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800450/compare-unique-value-with-three-column-in-r

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can do it as follows:

```
transform(df, ST2 = ave(as.character(CH), MAX, FUN = function(x) 
                    if(length(unique(x)) == 1) "Match" else "Not Match" ))

#  ID Num MAX    CH        ST       ST2
#1  1  22   A XCA-1 Not Match Not Match
#2  2  24   B VBS-7     Match     Match
#3  3  54   A XCA-1 Not Match Not Match
#4  4  48   A XCA-1 Not Match Not Match
#5  5  88   C CXV-4     Match     Match
#6  6  87   B VBS-7     Match     Match
#7  7  98   A VBS-0 Not Match Not Match
```

Comment: Beat me by not much, my function would have been `ifelse(all(x == x[1]), "Match", "Not Match")`.

Comment: @docendo discimus Thanks..:)

Comment: @docendo discimus For some cases i don't have `MAX` value in dataframe for that i want to check `ID` and `Num` in entire dataframe and whenever either `ID` or `Num` match anywhere in the dataframe that compare `CH` value of particular row and give `Match` if value same or `Not Match` in Status.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a category (the MAX column) and for each entry in MAX you want to determine if that category has unique values of the column CH. This is not reflected in the example you have currently posted, but seems to be what you are saying. If that is what you want, it can be done pretty easily with a `group_by()` strategy:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(ID  = 1:6, 
                  MAX = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B"), 
                  CH = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "C", "D"))
```

Here I am creating a dataframe in which the value of CH is always the same for when MAX == A or C, but not when it equals B. The result is then:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(MAX) %>% 
             mutate(Match = ifelse(length(unique(CH))==1, "Match", "No Match"))
df

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   MAX [3]
     ID MAX   CH    Match   
  <int> <fct> <fct> <chr>   
1     1 A     A     Match   
2     2 B     B     No Match
3     3 A     A     Match   
4     4 A     A     Match   
5     5 C     C     Match   
6     6 B     D     No Match
```